# How to think of $\vec{u}-\vec{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Assume I have two vectors, $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. I know that I can think of their sum via Triangle or Parallelogram Law, but I'm having trouble knowing which way the vector would point depending on if it was $\vec{u}-\vec{v}$ or if it was $\vec{v}-\vec{u}$. Is there an easy way to remember which way the arrow would point?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of memorizing the direction, you could try thinking
$$\vec{u} = (\vec{u}-\vec{v}) + \vec{v},$$
i.e., $\vec{u}-\vec{v}$ would point to the direction from the tip of $\vec{v}$ to the tip of $\vec{u}$.

Comment: Finally a way to remember :)

Answer (score 5):

Remember that $\vec{u}-\vec{0}=\vec{u}$ is the vector from the origin to $\vec{u}$. This reminds me that $\vec{u}-\vec{v}$ is in the direction from $\vec{v}$ to $\vec{u}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\vec{u} -\vec{v} = \vec{u} + (-\vec{v}) $
now the direction of $-\vec{v}$  is just $180^0$ opposite to that of direction of $\vec{v}. $ Now it is just addition of two vectors so you can determine direction

Answer (score 2):

You can think about $\vec{u}-\vec{v}$ as a translation of the origin from $\vec{0}$ to $\vec{v}$.  In this case $\vec{v}$ becomes the new origin and thus has the tail of the new vector.

Answer (score 2):

Understand and remember $Displacement=End-Start$. So in subtraction of vectors the result starts from tip of vector that is subtracted.